# Accessing column data from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file with A, B, C, D columns and N rows. 
The problems is that the data in these columns is not of the same length i.e some are 4.5 and some are 4.52.

My question is in two parts :

How do i access these columns from the csv files. 
I've used this code to print the contents of the csv file and to read them into an array

```
    import csv
    with open('file.csv','rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

to print the rows in the CSV file and i replaced

```
    print row
```

with

```
    z = row
    z.append(z)
```

to save the data into an array.

But z is a 1-D array. And the data is of type string. When i try performing operations of the type np.median(z), it gives me an error. Also, i cannot do

```
    z.append(float(z))
```

This is giving me a TypeError.

And, is there anyway to truncate the values and set them to a certain precision while we are importing them from the csv file?! Like, if the file has values like 4.3, 4.56, 4.299, ..., i want to constrain what i finally import to just one decimal point.

This SE question is the closest to answering my 2nd question - [Python - CSV: Large file with rows of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549746/python-csv-large-file-with-rows-of-different-lengths) - but i do not understand it. If any of you can help me regarding this, I'd be thankful.

EDIT 1 : 
@ Richie : here's a sample data set - http://goo.gl/io8Az. It links to a google doc. 
And regd your comment, this was the outcome with i ran your code on my csv file -

```
     ValueError: could not convert string to float: plate
```

@ Pieters : z = row, z.append(z) created this - 
['3836', '55302', '402', '22.945717', '22.771544', '23.081865', '22.428421', '21.78294', '164.40663689', '-1.25641627', '1.780485', '1237674648848106129', [...]].

I should've mentioned that i've just started using python and i'm learning things on a need-to-know basis! I'm improvising with bits and pieces of code i'm finding on the web.

EDIT 2: 
I've heard about pandas. I guess i should start using it.

@ Khalid - i've run your code and i'm able to retrieve the column i want. 
Instead of printing the whole row out, can i access it instead?! as a static array?!

EDIT 3: 
@ richie : the first time i ran your code, this showed up -

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 4, in 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: plate

well, i realized that the first row containing the column names is the cause, so i removed the first row, saved this as a new file and ran the code on that file and it worked perfectly fine.

But, if i do remove the first line, which contains the column identifiers, i cannot use the method mentioned by khalid below. I am looking at pandas in the meanwhile.

Thanks for everything guys :)

EDIT 4 : 
Lesson Learnt. Pandas is Awesome. Job Done :)...

Comment: You can use 'append' only with a list. Here is 'z=row' a list? Please can you share some sample data?

Comment: `z = row; z.append(z)` creates a self-referencing list. Is that really your code?

Answer (score 4):

A few things, depending on what you want to do. Here is the simple approach to get them referenced by columns:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    rows = list(reader)

for row in rows:
   print row['plate']
```

If you want to convert them to floats or ints, you can use `map`. However, I suspect you want to do some calculations in the end, and for that its better to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#csv).

As an added bonus, `pandas` will give you a 2D grid respresentation called a `DataFrame` of your file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
import csv
import numpy as np
class onefloat(float):
   def __repr__(self):
       return "%0.1f" % self
with open('file.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print map(onefloat,row) # your issue of 1 decimal point is taken care of here
        print '{:.1f}'.format(np.median(map(float,row))) # in case you want this too to be of 1 decimal point
```

And this is how it is done using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('richards_quasar_outliers.csv')
print data['plate'].median()
```

Comment: you ran into this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: plate` because `'plate'` is a header in your csv file. For more on how to ignore headers while reading a csv file see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11350095/1948860 . For now remove the headers and test the code.