# Get Values from last Row of .csv File

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am logging in `DataLogging.csv`Temperature and Humidity:

```
2016-04-07 09:36    16.0    48.7
2016-04-07 09:37    16.0    48.7
2016-04-07 09:38    16.0    48.7
2016-04-07 09:39    16.1    48.8
2016-04-07 09:40    16.1    48.7
```

`row[0]` gets me the Date, `row[1]` the Temp and `row[2]` Humidity

What is the fastest way to get the Temperature and Humidity Values from  the last row of the file(so those that have been logged last)? In this case the `09:40` values

@Edit: The Logger runs on a Raspberry Pi 2

I found this method: ([Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296955/reading-last-row-from-csv-file-python-error))

```
from collections import deque
import csv

def get_last_row(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as f:
        return deque(csv.reader(f), 1)[0]

lastline = ', '.join(get_last_row('DataLogger.csv'))
values = lastline.split("\t")
print ((values[1]))
```

now I get the Temperature Value from the Last line ....

Comment: This problem is basically [`How to access the last line of a file`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail), plus a parsing of this last line to [access a particular column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186893/accessing-column-data-from-a-csv-file-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on a Unix-y system so something simple like this should work + it's fast because it doesn't read the whole file:

```
import subprocess
last_line = subprocess.check_output(["tail", "-1", "DataLogging.csv"])
# to get the values (parsing via the csv module seems excessive for one line)
temp_hum = [float(x) for x in last_line.split()[2:]]
```

A cross-platform solution using `seek()` could be made by implemeting `tail`s approach. A comment in [`tail`'s source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c#n464) explains how it works:

> Print the last N_LINES lines from the end of file FD.    Go backward
>   through the file, reading 'BUFSIZ' bytes at a time (except    probably
>   the first), until we hit the start of the file or have    read NUMBER
>   newlines.    START_POS is the starting position of the read pointer
>   for the file    associated with FD (may be nonzero).    END_POS is the
>   file offset of EOF (one larger than offset of last byte).    Return
>   true if successful.

Comment: @PeterS Cool cool. I wonder if the `deque` solution will read the entire file from start to end. It might not be an issue now but if your file grows substantially, `tail`has the advantage of reading backwards.  From [`tail`'s source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c#n464): *"Go backward through the file, reading 'BUFSIZ' bytes at a time (except probably the first), until we hit the start of the file or have read NUMBER newlines."*

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure wether or not it reads through the whole file. For now it works pretty fast (20.000 lines in the file, about 2 Weeks measurements) I'd probably have to switch to you version when my pi just can't handle it anymore :-) Thank