# finding a joint set between text file and csv file

Tags: python, csv

trying to compare list of names from a text file, with a list of names from a csv file.

ive created a set of names from the text file using the following:

```
# receive text and create new list
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    names = []
    # add first 5 characters from lines to list to get name
    for x in lines[9:1011]:
        names.append(x[0:5])
        names.sort()
        # create set from list to eliminate duplicates
unique_name = set(names)
print(unique_name)
```

now id like to compare the set with a csv table with a name column and was wondering what the best way to do this is?
thank you

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186893/accessing-column-data-from-a-csv-file-in-python#17188290  Accessing column data from a CSV file in Python

Comment: maybe first don't search `the best way` but `working way`

Comment: first you have to load csv file and create list with rows. And later you can use `for`-loop to check every row in list and compare every name with `set(names)`. OR use `pandas` to make it simpler.