# How do i make pre-defined keys for only two of the rows in a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

[CSV is of the format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IniGA.png)

I want to make a dictionary that when printed will return:

```
{
'Date': '######'
'Cash': '20000'
'SKY': '5'
'EZJ': '8'
}
```

so far I have

```
import csv
import pprint
portfolio = {}

def loadPortfolio(fname):
    try:
        with open(fname, "rt") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                key = row[0]
                portfolio[key] = row[1:]
        pprint.pprint(portfolio)
```

I basically want to know how to make keys for only the first two rows and have the second two rows have their keys taken from the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549746/2381553) and its answers, you can retrieve the number of token per row with `len(row)`.

You can use another variable to keep track of the current row number if you need to.

You `for`loop should look like this :

```
int row_number = 0
for row in reader:
    key = ''
    if len(row) > 1:
        key = row[0]
    else:
        key = 'CUSTOM_KEY'  # Depends on the row current row_number

    portfolio[key] = row[1:]
    row_number += 1
```

REMARK: This will not only work for the first rows but also for every row with less than 2 tokens. If you do not specify a specific key for all the rows with only 1 token, the default value for `key` will be used instead (in this case en empty str `''`).